# "-" en dash giving different ascii values

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, ascii, unicode-string

I have read it  that endash is not ASCII however, the following code shows:

```
print(ord('-'))
>>>45
```

So, is it ASCII or not?

Secondly, when I looked for the Ascii again for "endash", "-"  the ASCII code shows 8211.

```
 for c in "wireless enhancements – extra costs":
    print(c , ord(c))
```

> > – 8211

I am not able to understand this endash. Please explain

Comment: Well, the first is a minus sign, the second is an en dash. The en dash is slightly wider, and doesn't form part of ascii.

Comment: Presumably the first one is the hyphen or minus sign `-` (ASCII), whereas the second is the endash (Unicode)

Comment: Thanks .  JohanC ,Jammy Dodger

Answer (score 2):

The `-` character in the below code is ['U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS'](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002d/index.htm):

```
print(ord('-'))
```

The `–` character in the below code is ['U+2013 EN DASH'](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm):

```
for c in "wireless enhancements – extra costs":
```

You can use this site to check for yourself: https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html

Comment: Thanks @ruohola.  Also, in windows, we do not have any way to write endash directly.

Comment: @PayalBhatia in some word processors, typing a `-` (hypen) on the keyboard will insert an endash into the document instead.